# Hyper-V not connecting windows 10, how to fix that?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v

My windows 10 machine continuosly showing as connecting.

[image]

And after sometime, I am getting an error:

[image]

So, I need to exit and turnoff the machine and connect again.
This is happening whenever I close the window and using in the background and need to connect after sometime later.

Please suggest how to fix this?

My host machine OS:

OS details:

[image]

Once I start the machine, it is working.
But in the middle if I close the window, it is not connecting and giving this error.
When I turnoff and start again it will work.

Comment: Have you ever been able to open the console to this particular Hyper-V VM?  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Have you waited for the VM to finish stopping? This should be visible in its status on the Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: After I connect immediately after power on it is working, but after sometime when I close the window and connect again, it is giving this error. To connect again, I need to turn off the machine and turn on again. Multiple machines same issue.